# Weird issue with running thread::sleep in a loop in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, rust, rust-tokio, rancher, rust-rocket

I am only able to reproduce this issue in my rancher kubernetes cloud. Locally it runs fine. However, if I spawn a new thread which calls sleep in a loop. Rocket will hang and I don't know why.

```
tokio::spawn(async move {
  loop {
    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1));
  }
});
```

This makes it really hard to know run some function every x seconds.

Comment: Is that `std::thread::sleep`?

Comment: You really don't want to do any blocking operations inside the *async* context. You should change that to some asynchronous version of sleep (for example `tokio::time::sleep`).

Comment: Also small naming issue.  You haven't spawn a new thread, but a new task. Tokio uses by default a multi-threaded work-stealing executor. Meaning that it will spawn firstly some number of worker threads and then they will poll task you spawned to completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using tokio::time::sleep instead as explained by @aleksander-krauze in the comments fixed the issue.